# Rspec producing a undefined method `route_to' , despite having rspec/rails defined in gemfile/rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

**QUESTION: What have I done wrong that the route_to method remains undefined?**

I'm very new to this but I'm trying to develop some route tests via the rspec gem.

My issue is that I am obtaining the error:

```
undefined method `route_to' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::RouteToHomepage
```

I have already looked through the API for this query, and I've already done the following:

```
Install gem 'rspec-rails'
```

In rails_helper.rb

```
    require 'rspec/rails'
```

In my routing_spec.rb (where I am writing the routes)

```
    require 'rails_helper'

    describe "route to homepage" do
      it "routes /home to index" do
        expect(:get => "/homes").to route_to(
          action: "index"
        )
      end
    end
```

What exactly do I need to change or add, so the "route_to" method is defined? I've already read around and apparently it's defined in the "rspec-rails" gem, which I have, and already included.

Comment: Try specifying the spec type as routing, if you haven't added the `infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` configuration option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/routing-specs):

> Routing specs are marked by `:type => :routing` or if you have set
>   `config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` by placing them in `spec/routing`.

---

You didn't say where the `routing_spec.rb` is located, but *if* it's inside the folder `spec/routing/` then you could choose to enable the above config option.

Otherwise, or in general, you must do this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "route to homepage", type: :routing do
  it "routes /home to index" do
    expect(:get => "/homes").to route_to(
      action: "index"
    )
  end
end
```

Doing this will include the necessary RSpec helper that defines `route_to`, among other methods.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for that Tom, I didn't realise I was missing a little code.